# Same query, same system, different execution time

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

The queries below all execute instantly on our development server where as they can take upto 2 minutes 20 seconds.

The query execution time seems to be affected by home ambiguous the LIKE string's are. If they closely match a country that has few matches it will take less time, and if you use something like 'ge' for germany - it will take longer to execute. But this doesn't always work out like that, at times its quite erratic.

Sending data appears to be the culprit but why and what does that mean. Also memory on production looks to be quite low (free memory)?

**Production:**
Intel Quad Xeon E3-1220 3.1GHz
4GB DDR3
2x 1TB SATA in RAID1
Network speed 100Mb
Ubuntu

**Development**
Intel Core i3-2100, 2C/4T, 3.10GHz
500 GB SATA - No RAID
4GB DDR3

This query is NOT the query in question but is related so ill post it.

```
SELECT 
    f.form_question_has_answer_id 
FROM 
    form_question_has_answer f 
INNER JOIN 
    project_company_has_user p ON f.form_question_has_answer_user_id = p.project_company_has_user_user_id 
INNER JOIN 
    company c ON p.project_company_has_user_company_id = c.company_id 
INNER JOIN 
    project p2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = p2.project_id 
INNER JOIN 
    user u ON p.project_company_has_user_user_id = u.user_id 
INNER JOIN 
    form f2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = f2.form_project_id 
WHERE 
    (f2.form_template_name = 'custom' AND p.project_company_has_user_garbage_collection = 0 AND p.project_company_has_user_project_id = '29') AND (LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%ge%' OR LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%abcde%') AND f.form_question_has_answer_form_id = '174'
```

And the explain plan for the above query is, run on both dev and production produce the same plan.

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                | key                              | key_len | ref                                                | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p2    | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 4       | const                                              |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref    | form_question_has_answer_form_id,form_question_has_answer_user_id                                                                            | form_question_has_answer_form_id | 4       | const                                              |  796 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 4       | new_klarents.f.form_question_has_answer_user_id    |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref    | project_company_has_user_unique_key,project_company_has_user_user_id,project_company_has_user_company_id,project_company_has_user_project_id | project_company_has_user_user_id | 4       | new_klarents.f.form_question_has_answer_user_id    |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f2    | ref    | form_project_id                                                                                                                              | form_project_id                  | 4       | const                                              |   15 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 4       | new_klarents.p.project_company_has_user_company_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

This query takes 2 minutes ~20 seconds to execute.

The query that is ACTUALLY being run on the server is this one:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS num_results 
FROM (SELECT 
        f.form_question_has_answer_id 
    FROM 
        form_question_has_answer f 
    INNER JOIN 
        project_company_has_user p ON f.form_question_has_answer_user_id = p.project_company_has_user_user_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        company c ON p.project_company_has_user_company_id = c.company_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        project p2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = p2.project_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        user u ON p.project_company_has_user_user_id = u.user_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        form f2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = f2.form_project_id 
    WHERE 
        (f2.form_template_name = 'custom' AND p.project_company_has_user_garbage_collection = 0 AND p.project_company_has_user_project_id = '29') AND (LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%ge%' OR LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%abcde%') AND f.form_question_has_answer_form_id = '174' 
    GROUP BY 
        f.form_question_has_answer_id;) dctrn_count_query;
```

With explain plans (again same on dev and production):

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                            | key                              | key_len | ref                                                | rows | Extra                        |
    +----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
    |  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL  | NULL   | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                     | NULL                             | NULL    | NULL                                               | NULL | Select tables optimized away |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | p2    | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                          | 4       |                                                    |    1 | Using index                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | f     | ref    | form_question_has_answer_form_id,form_question_has_answer_user_id                                                                                                                        | form_question_has_answer_form_id | 4       |                                                    |  797 | Using where                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | p     | ref    | project_company_has_user_unique_key,project_company_has_user_user_id,project_company_has_user_company_id,project_company_has_user_project_id,project_company_has_user_garbage_collection | project_company_has_user_user_id | 4       | new_klarents.f.form_question_has_answer_user_id    |    1 | Using where                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | f2    | ref    | form_project_id                                                                                                                                                                          | form_project_id                  | 4       |                                                    |   15 | Using where                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                          | 4       | new_klarents.p.project_company_has_user_company_id |    1 | Using where                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                          | 4       | new_klarents.p.project_company_has_user_user_id    |    1 | Using where; Using index     |
    +----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
```

On the production server the information I have is as follows.

Upon execution:

```
+-------------+
| num_results |
+-------------+
|           3 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (2 min 14.28 sec)
```

Show profile:

```
+--------------------------------+------------+
| Status                         | Duration   |
+--------------------------------+------------+
| starting                       |   0.000016 |
| checking query cache for query |   0.000057 |
| Opening tables                 |   0.004388 |
| System lock                    |   0.000003 |
| Table lock                     |   0.000036 |
| init                           |   0.000030 |
| optimizing                     |   0.000016 |
| statistics                     |   0.000111 |
| preparing                      |   0.000022 |
| executing                      |   0.000004 |
| Sorting result                 |   0.000002 |
| Sending data                   | 136.213836 |
| end                            |   0.000007 |
| query end                      |   0.000002 |
| freeing items                  |   0.004273 |
| storing result in query cache  |   0.000010 |
| logging slow query             |   0.000001 |
| logging slow query             |   0.000002 |
| cleaning up                    |   0.000002 |
+--------------------------------+------------+
```

On development the results are as follows.

```sql
+-------------+
| num_results |
+-------------+
|           3 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

Again the profile for this query:

```sql
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000022 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000148 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000025 |
| System lock                    | 0.000008 |
| Table lock                     | 0.000101 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000035 |
| statistics                     | 0.001019 |
| preparing                      | 0.000047 |
| executing                      | 0.000008 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                   | 0.086565 |
| init                           | 0.000015 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000006 |
| executing                      | 0.000020 |
| end                            | 0.000004 |
| query end                      | 0.000004 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000028 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000005 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000008 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000008 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000002 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000005 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

If i remove user and/or project innerjoins the query is reduced to 30s.

Last bit of information I have:

Mysqlserver and Apache are on the same box, there is only one box for production.

Production output from top: before & after.

```
top - 15:43:25 up 78 days, 12:11,  4 users,  load average: 1.42, 0.99, 0.78
Tasks: 162 total,   2 running, 160 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us, 50.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4037868k total,  3772580k used,   265288k free,   243704k buffers
Swap:  3905528k total,   265384k used,  3640144k free,  1207944k cached

top - 15:44:31 up 78 days, 12:13,  4 users,  load average: 1.94, 1.23, 0.87
Tasks: 160 total,   2 running, 157 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us, 50.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4037868k total,  3834300k used,   203568k free,   243736k buffers
Swap:  3905528k total,   265384k used,  3640144k free,  1207804k cached
```

But this isn't a good representation of production's normal status so here is a grab of it from today outside of executing the queries.

```
top - 11:04:58 up 79 days,  7:33,  4 users,  load average: 0.39, 0.58, 0.76
Tasks: 156 total,   1 running, 155 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.3%us,  2.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 93.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4037868k total,  3676136k used,   361732k free,   271480k buffers
Swap:  3905528k total,   268736k used,  3636792k free,  1063432k cached
```

Development: This one doesn't change during or after.

```
top - 15:47:07 up 110 days, 22:11,  7 users,  load average: 0.17, 0.07, 0.06
Tasks: 210 total,   2 running, 208 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4111972k total,  1821100k used,  2290872k free,   238860k buffers
Swap:  4183036k total,    66472k used,  4116564k free,   921072k cached
```

Comment: How much data is in the development database vs. the production database?

Comment: Also, is development local and production on the network?

Comment: The databases are exact matches, development uses a daily dump from live.

Comment: Are these timings consistent, is your production server always taking that long to send you this single-row, single-column result?

Comment: No they aren't on the same network, production is a leased dedicated server, development is on our internal network - to run the test on dev I ran it from through an external address, not from on the network

Comment: Production is always slow the first run, but it can be a bit hit and miss after the first run of the query, Dev is always fast each and everytime.

Comment: This might be an issue with your data center's network. Can you login to the production server and run the mysql client there to test that query locally?

Comment: The output above is is run from commandline of either development or production servers (ssh login)

Comment: Try progressively simplifying your posted query (remove JOINs one by one) and see _when_ that makes production equal to development. Perhaps, different production tables are stored on different drives and one of the drives is starting to fail? Or the drive is somehow used through a network share (which would make it slow)?

Comment: I removed the project/user innerjoins and reduced the query to 30s, should I post the explain-plan for the new queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the slowness is intermittent, it's either server load or other resource contention (in your case, most likely memory). Your system needs to have enough RAM to store all of the indexes in memory at once, otherwise, it will have to swap out memory if the needed index isn't already loaded in RAM.

Your TOP results show that there is a low amount of RAM available.

Use the [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) setting to configure the size of the buffer pool for InnoDB, and [key_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-key-cache.html) for MyISAM. Ensure you set it high enough to hold all of the indexes in RAM at the same time, and that your system has enough RAM to accomplish this.

Comment: The slowness is everytime I run the query when its not cached. If I remove inner joins for user and/or project the result is reduced to a 30s execution! What does this mean?

Comment: @mr12086, Use [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to confirm that it's caching vs memory swapping.

Comment: I'm running the query with the SQL_NO_CACHE param, but what is this supposed to show me? It just means each time I run the query its not cached so takes > 2minutes each time.  Would something else happen if it was to do with memory swapping?

Comment: If it was still faster the second time even without the query cache, then it would point pretty definitively to memory swapping, however if it's still slow the second time without the cache, it's still unknown if it's the issue.

Comment: The SQL_CACHE and SQL_NO_CACHE modifiers were used with the query cache prior to MySQL 8.0. The query cache was removed in MySQL 8.0. The SQL_CACHE modifier was removed as well. SQL_NO_CACHE is deprecated, and has no effect; expect it to be removed in a future MySQL release.

Answer (score 0):

Sending data                   | 136.213836

Obviously :D

This must be some kind of infrastructure issue... Network or something, Try to ping your server from your sql/plus terminal and you will have your answer

Comment: @aF Exactly. And what makes thing mysterious is that he's just returning single value (`COUNT(*)`), so this is no mere bandwidth issue.

Answer (score 0):

An explain-plan is usually the best place to start whenever you have a slow query. To get one, run

```
DESCRIBE SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS num_results 
FROM (SELECT 
        f.form_question_has_answer_id 
    FROM 
        form_question_has_answer f 
    INNER JOIN 
        project_company_has_user p ON f.form_question_has_answer_user_id = p.project_company_has_user_user_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        company c ON p.project_company_has_user_company_id = c.company_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        project p2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = p2.project_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        user u ON p.project_company_has_user_user_id = u.user_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        form f2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = f2.form_project_id 
    WHERE 
        (f2.form_template_name = 'custom' AND p.project_company_has_user_garbage_collection = 0 AND p.project_company_has_user_project_id = '29') AND (LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%finland%' OR LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%finnland%') AND f.form_question_has_answer_form_id = '174' 
    GROUP BY 
        f.form_question_has_answer_id;) dctrn_count_query;
```

This will show you a table listing the steps required to execute your query. If you see a large value in the 'rows' column and NULL in the 'key' column, that indicates that your query having to scan a large number of rows to determine which ones to return.

In that case, adding an index on destination_id should dramatically speed your query, at some cost to insert and delete speed (since the index will also need to be updated).

Comment: Both queries are identical, run on identical database structure and on identical amounts of data, so they should be equally well (or badly) optimized.

Comment: Then like @Sebas stated, bandwidth problem in production!

Comment: The descibe/explain plan is listed above, it might not be perfect but I don't think its something that should be doing this :)

Answer (score 0):

If this [link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,241461,242012#msg-242012) is correct the number behind 'sending data' is not the time needed for sending data but for "Sorting result".

This in turn might hint to a memory or CPU issue on the production server. You might want to look into the relevant statistics on the machines.

Answer (score 0):

Run the queries in development and production and compare the query plans. If they are different, try updating statistics on the tables involved in the query.

Comment: The plans are identical, everything about the two is identical apart their execute times.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that occurs to me is a configuration difference between the two MySQL servers. Is there any significant difference in the memory setup between the two servers?  Is it a virtual server?

Also, is the load on the production server very high?

Comment: Server load on production is minimal, never really high and definitely not currently. - I've added the top output in the OP.

Comment: Looking again at the profile, "Opening tables" is also significantly slower on the development machine. I suspect a memory problem of some kind. There is a significant difference in the used memory. Development machine: "Mem:   4111972k total,  1821100k used," Production "Mem:   4037868k total,  3817944k used,"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intimately familiar with the optimizer in mysql.

This problem is occuring at the end of the query.  One possibility is a look that is occuring on the production system.  For instance, perhaps there is some sort of lock on metadata that prevents a new table from being created.

Also, the environment where a query runs *does* affect the optimizer.  At the very least, multiple threads/processors will have an impact on the query plan.  Mysql could generate different query optimizations based on available resources.  I know SQL Server will produce different query plans based on available memory -- using hash tables when there is enough memory but nested loop joins when less is available.  Are the memory allcoations exactly the same on both systems?

Comment: Im going to come clean in the I have no idea about memory allocation, both boxes are linux both have 4GB, Ill take a snap of 'top' on both boxes and post it in a moment.